# "Центр": прописная или строчная?

Tags: прописная-строчная

разрешите, пожалуйста, наш спор. Дело в том, что местная газета в целях удобочитаемости не пишет название организации целиком. То есть, вместо ГБОУ-СОШ №13 пишет школа №13 и т.д. Впрос вот в чем: наша школа называется ГБОУ СОШ "Центр образования" - с какой буквы газета должна писать "центр" при сокращении? В центре образования прошел открытый урок... или В Центре образования прошел открытый урок?

Comment: Из  названия  школы  вытекает - с  прописной  и  в  кавычках.

Comment: Из названия вытекает, что надо писать ***ГБОУ СОШ "Центр образования" ***
Но автор спрашивает о сокращенном написании/названии, которому этот фофициоз - не указ. 
Хотя в другом случае Вы будете правы. Правильным ***официальным*** названием является то, которое в уставных документах. И плевать там хотели на правила.

Answer (score 4):

Хороший вопрос. Интересно, кто-нибудь найдет правило с подобными примерами? С одной стороны, это приложение. Вроде, кинотеатр "Россия" - в "России". И тогда в отсутствии главного слова мы должны писать не только с большой буквы, но и в кавычках. В "Центре образования". Мне кажется это правильным.

Но вот наша школа официально называется МБОУ "СОШ №2" (для непосвященных: муниципальное бюджетное общеобразовательное учреждение "Средняя общеобразовательная школа №2" ) Но по-простому-то: В средней школе №2. С большой буквы  - В Средней школе - не пишут,в кавычках - В "Средней школе" тоже, и представить даже не могу.... Может, потому, что многие десятилетия школа так и называлась  - школа, а не МБОУ "СОШ №" или "ГБОУ "СОШ№"

Comment: Подобные названия, в которых два раза повторяется слово *общеобразовательный* - даже маразмом не хочется называть. Стыд и срам! *Шкрабы голодают*.

Comment: Что-то у вас  все время грубо... Учителя нипричем. Министерство рулит.

Comment: Конечно, ни при чем! Учителя заняты сеянием *разумного, доброго, вечного*, они никак не могут возвысить свой голос...

ГБОУ СОШ "Центр образования". Троекратное образование, во дают чиновники!

Answer (score 3):

Здесь вопрос вот в чем: если  написать: "В центре образования прошел открытый урок" .то не совсем ясно будет о каком центре образования идет речь.А прописная буква сразу указывает ,что это название какого-то учреждения, т.е. имя собственное.

Comment: >не совсем ясно будет о каком центре образования идет речь  
  
Даже из Вашего текста следует, что заглавная не снимает эту "не совсем ясность". 

>то название какого-то 
Вряд ли это можно считать названием. 
И вот как раз Вашем примере я бы не рискнул рекомендовать заглавную.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы подобные названия писал с заглавной - как условные наименования, т.е. имя собственное. По тем же причинам, например, в договорах "... далее именуемые Сторонами" - с заглавной.

Средняя школа - это не условное обозначение, а вполне обычное. С номером. Который и выступает в качестве имени собственного.